# How to give extra permission at document library (child) level?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, document, access

I want to grant edit permissions at document library level and view permissions at a site level. When I tried to give edit permission to a person at library level. This permission automatically replicates to site level as well.

Note: Library is not inheriting permission from the site.

Is there any way to do it

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way for you to achieve what you want without some permissions manipulation. The best practice is to give people the minimum rights necessary to do their work at the highest level so that cascades down to all the lists and libraries. Then in cases where user groups need more or less restriction, you break permission inheritance on the list or library and change permissions as necessary.

The point here is that if you have a good group setup in your site, then it is really just a matter of adding users to the appropriate group and by doing so, they get all the rights and privileges afforded to them where the group is used.

Adding users individually is a bad practice and makes management more tedious and time consuming than it needs to be.

Comment: Great we're on the same thinking.  We have given people the minimum rights necessary to do their work at the highest level.  The problem is when we get to the document library level and the permissions are broke, SharePoint does not allow a group to be added, only users.  I would have expect to be able to add extra groups to the document library without breaking permissions.  Can you give me suggestions for managing permissions better?

Comment: If you can't add groups to the document library after breaking inheritance, that is definitely a problem, you should open a case with Microsoft support about that because that is not normal.

Answer (score 1):

You have to click "Break Inheritance" in the library permission settings, then make your changes there.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  If we break permissions on each document library that would make management of library's in future more cumbersome.  Can you recommend a way for additional permissions to be added (Rather than break permissions)?

Comment: No. If permissions are inherited, they have to be exactly the same. That's what inherited permissions means. If the majority of the site will be the libraries with these specific permissions, I would set the whole site's permissions that way, and break inheritance on the rest. Use the site level to grant permissions that will be most common. You could write a timer job in .NET to check for libraries that meet a certain condition and change the permissions on those. But OOTB, different permissions at different levels have to be defined at those levels.